# iPhone: Annotation view (like MKAnnotationView) for route-me project?

Tags: iphone, mapkit, mkannotation, route-me

I am using the [route-me](https://github.com/route-me/route-me) project to show some (offline) maps I have made using [TileMill](http://mapbox.com/tilemill/) . So far, so good. The problem now is how to display a beautiful annotation view like the MKAnnotationView from MapKit (the callout bubble - marker balloons). As far as I know, there are no annotation views in the route-me project, so, if I want to use one I have to implement it by myself.

Do you know guys if there are already any solutions or any open source code for an annotation view using the route-me project?

Would be glad to hear any feedback. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [alpstein](https://github.com/Alpstein/route-me) fork of the route-me project.   Or the [mapbox/tilemill](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-sdk) fork.  They both have annotations.